# JWT Authentication issue

Tags: django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-jwt

guys,
This would be my first post here, so I would try to be as more specific as possible.
I am having this project where I need to use JWT tokens for authentication. The idea is to generate token with custom payload, which includes the last reset date of the user. At the process of logging in I am creating the token as follows the code:

```
payload={
                    'sub':'authorization_token',
                    'iss':'dani',
                    'aud':'something',
                    'exp': datetime.utcnow() + JWT_AUTH.get('JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA'),
                    'password_reset_time': str(user.reset_request_time),
                    'user_id':user.pk

                }
                self.token = jwt.encode(payload, SECRET_KEY, algorithm='HS256')
```

When I am sending logging in post via Postman, as a response I am receiving the token, loaded with the needed information. The thing is that we're having this validation view for testing purposes:

```
class ValidateView(APIView):
permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
SERVER_LOG.error('HelloView: %s', "123")
def get(self, request):
    content = {'validated': True}
    return Response(content)
```

So,if the token is correctly authenticated, it should return to me:

```
 {
    "validated": true
 }
```

Instead, I am receiving :

```
{
    "detail": "Incorrect authentication credentials."
}
```

I am still noob in Django, and my suggestion is that the piece of code, which is responsible for authenticating my token does not know about the changes I made in the payload, so in the process of decoding, it's expecting different format of payload or different type of information in it, so my latest thoughts are that I should create some custom Validation view for the token and to specify the format of the payload that should be decoded. Every suggestion or guidance, regarding the problem I am facing would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the token in the header?

```
Authorization: Bearer <your token goes here>
```